# Multiple DKIM and SPF records on Google Apps/G Suite/Google Workspace for MailChimp

Tags: dns, mailchimp, spf, dkim, google-workspace

I'm looking to add SPF and DKIM to my domain for [MailChimp](https://kb.mailchimp.com/accounts/email-authentication/set-up-custom-domain-authentication-dkim-and-spf).

The domain in question is running through G Suite and has the following TXT record for SPF:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

The domain also has a TXT record for Google DKIM.

I've read via the [MailChimp](https://kb.mailchimp.com/accounts/email-authentication/set-up-custom-domain-authentication-dkim-and-spf) and [G Suite](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4568483?hl=en) docs that you shouldn't add more than one SPF record. With this in mind, would this be the correct way of adding MailChimp's SPF record?

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all include:servers.mcsv.net ?all
```

Do the same rules apply for DKIM or am I okay to add multiple records for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you can only have a single SPF record for a domain. The right way to combine those is:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:servers.mcsv.net ~all
```

You should never use `?all` as the default action – it's as bad as not having SPF at all.

DKIM is different – you need a selector as the DNS name, so if Mailchimp uses a selector called `mc` (their docs will say), you would put their key in a record called `mc._domainkey.example.com` (substituting your domain for `example.com`). You can have many such selector records, and they are all independent.

You might like to look into creating a DMARC config as well.

Comment: According to https://mailchimp.com/help/set-up-custom-domain-authentication-dkim-and-spf/ I think this record isn't necessary anymore. Am I wrong?

Comment: It's not that it's not necessary, it's that CNAMEs provide an alternative means of achieving the same thing. It makes it easier for Mailchimp because they get more control over DNS (because to be fair, getting customers to make accurate changes to their DNS servers is hard!), but it does so by taking that control away from you. It's entirely reasonable to support both mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, when we add a custom record with two SPF servers

Google Workspace has default rule with add again this TXT record :

"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"

And then, it appears twice on the public TXT zone

Does that work ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).